# How do you bind parameters to a SQL statement in SQLite3 for C++?

Tags: c++, sql, c, sqlite

I'm trying to input data stored in variables from jobs I generate to a SQL table via C++, though I keep getting a (null) error message.

I've tried reading through the documentation but I'm still relatively new to C++ so I don't think I'm fully understanding the nuance of how exactly they want a variable SQL statement to be processed. I tried two different ways so far from what I found by searching around, and I seem to always be getting a SQL error = (null).

The first thing I tried was this: (note the db is opened in another function, and it works perfectly fine for the other execution of a static SQL statement I had earlier.)

```
void Access_Database::insertAirportJobs(float pay, int expire, float weight, Airport ap, Airport source)
{
     char* zErrMsg = 0; // Error message var
     char* sql;
     const char* pArg = "Row Tested";
     snprintf(sql, sizeof(sql), "INSERT INTO JOBS (airport_ID,dest,pay,expire,weight) " \
     "VALUES (%i, %i, %f, %i, %f ); ", source.airport_ID, ap.airport_ID, pay, expire, weight);
     sql[sizeof(sql) - 1] = '\0';

     int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, jobsCallback, (void*)pArg, &zErrMsg); // Execute the SQL statement that was passed in.

     if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "\nSQL error: %s\n\n", zErrMsg);
         sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
     }
     else
     {
         fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
     }
}
```

That didn't work, and gave that error message I noted earlier, so then I went back to hunting on google and found this solution:

```
void Access_Database::insertAirportJobs(float pay, int expire, float weight, Airport ap, Airport source)
{
    char* zErrMsg = 0; // Error message var
    const char* sql = "INSERT INTO JOBS (airport_ID,dest,pay,expire,weight) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    const char* pszTest;
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, &pszTest);
    if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, source.airport_ID);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, ap.airport_ID);
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, pay);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, expire);
        sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 5, weight);
        
        // Commit the binds

        sqlite3_step(stmt);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    }
    
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nSQL error: %s\n\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }
}
```

This didn't work either, and gave the same error. If I put the code that shows up when I use a breakpoint to examine what's going on into the server in a gui instead, it works perfectly fine. I don't really know what's going wrong because the error message didn't really help me find anything good on google. Perhaps one of you can just educate me as to a proper method for a dynamic SQL statement for SQLite3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apparently I had been closing the database earlier in the function that I was using to call this one. Oops. The second example basically worked with some minor modifications.

Comment: the first solution is not working, `snprintf` does not allocate any memory. You need to provide the function with a memory area (example: char SqlRequest[100] or dynamically allocated memory with malloc)

Comment: in the second solution, seems OK at a first glance, but there is something wrong in the logic. The point of the statement is to keep it and reuse it several times, in your example you just use it one time. You may store it in your class, and initialize at beginning, destroy it at the end.

Comment: If you need more information about the error, you might want to print the error with `sqlite3_errmsg(Database)`

Comment: @Robert For the first example, I tried to initialise it as NULL first, then set it up the size like sizeof(*sql) instead because I thought that's what you meant, though I still got an error message that said bad parameter or other API misuse. For the second one I just fixed the error message printer and it printed the same error as the first one. The point of the code is to reuse it. I don't really know what you mean by that second comment as this function gets called every time a new "job" gets created in the program. Any ideas?

Comment: FIXED IT. I apparently had closed my database earlier in the function and that's why it wasn't able to access it. Oops. @Robert

Answer (score 0):

In your first version `sql` is uninitialised, even if it wasn't then `sizeof(sql)` returns the size of the pointer not the size of the array.

In your second version your error message is null because you never assign a value to it, you should call `sqlite3_errmsg`, you shouldn't call `sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);` as sqlite manages it's own memory for error messages.

Comment: Actually, if `sqlite3_exec()` sets an error message, it *should* be freed via `sqlite3_free()` when you're done with it, like [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) says. Not for OP's second block of code, of course.

Comment: @Shawn OK, yes I was talking about the second version

Comment: For the first example, I tried to initialise it as NULL first, then set it up the size like `sizeof(*sql)` instead because I thought that's what you meant, though I still got an error message that said bad parameter or other API misuse.
For the second one I just fixed the error message printer and it printed the same error as the first one. Any ideas @AlanBirtles?

Comment: FIXED IT. I apparently had closed my database earlier in the function and that's why it wasn't able to access it. Oops. @AlanBirtles